# C# - Encrypt and Decrypt audio file with PGP (Error: inputStream must be seek-able)

Tags: c#, encryption, audio, stream, pgp

Context: Encrypt and Decrypt an audio file (.wav) in Azure Storage.
Issue: inputStream must be seek-able (when encrypting) "await pgp.EncryptStreamAsync(sourceStream, outputStream);"

I'm not a C# Developer :)

Thank you for your help,

Here is the code i'm using:

```
 static async Task Main()
    {
        
        string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING");
        ////Create a unique name for the container
        string containerName = "audioinput";
        string filename = "abc.wav";

        //// Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        BlobContainerClient sourcecontainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        BlobClient blobClient = sourcecontainer.GetBlobClient(filename);

        if (sourcecontainer.Exists())
        {

            var sourceStream = new MemoryStream();
            
                //Download blob to MemoryStream
                await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(sourceStream);
                sourceStream.Position = 0;
                
                //OutputStream
                await using var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
                
                //Get encryptionkeys
                EncryptionKeys encryptionKeys;
                using (Stream publicKeyStream = new FileStream(@"...\public.asc", FileMode.Open))
                    encryptionKeys = new EncryptionKeys(publicKeyStream);

                PGP pgp = new PGP(encryptionKeys);

            await pgp.EncryptStreamAsync(sourceStream, outputStream);
            

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("container doesn't exist");
        }

    }
```

Comment: What line is causing error?

Comment: Hello,
await pgp.EncryptStreamAsync(sourceStream, outputStream);

Comment: Check the length property of the surceStream to see how many bytes are in the stream.  Also check the position.  I'm pretty sure a MemoryStream is seekable.  It may be the method blobClient.DownloadToAsync() has a bug.

Comment: What's the impact of the number of bytes in the stream?

sourcestream values:
Capacity: 4109184
Position:0
Length: 3669164

Comment: Really just wanted to me sure there was data.  Max is usually 10M.  New new MemoryStream() with no parameter is seekable.  I think there is something wrong in this function that is changing the property of the memory stream : await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(sourceStream);